# Add module-generated pages to Drupal 7's search index

Tags: search, routes

I have a custom module that provides pages via hook_menu(). The *page callback* returns HTML-formatted output that is then displayed. The information is fetched from an external database, so it is not a  node/custom content type.

Since the displayed information is somehow the heart of this Drupal site, I want to add the information to Drupal's search index.

How can I facilitate this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement [`hook_search_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_update_index/7) to describe your new search type.
2. Implement [`hook_update_index()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_update_index/7), build up the content you wanted to be indexed, and throw it over to [`search_index()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.module/function/search_index/7) (see the example in `hook_update_index()`).
3. Profit.

Be sure to follow all the advice in the comments in the linked functions, and check out the core node and user modules' implementations of these hooks for examples of exactly what you need to do. The comments for [`hook_search_execute()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_search_execute/7) should also prove pretty helpful.